# How can I solve this error during running CNN model with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

When running my CNN model, below are my code with Keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=90,    
        width_shift_range=0.2,  
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.3, 
        horizontal_flip = True, 
        vertical_flip = True,
        zca_whitening = True, 
        brightness_range=[0.2,1.2], 
        fill_mode='wrap')

test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset",
                                          target_size=(256,256),
                                          batch_size = 32,
                                          class_mode = 'binary')
                                         
test_dataset = test.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset",
                                          target_size=(256,256),
                                          batch_size = 32,
                                          class_mode = 'binary')

model = keras.Sequential()

# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 1
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))

# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 2
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))

# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 3
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))

# Flattening Operation
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

# Fully Connected layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu'))

## Output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))  

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

train_imagesize = 327
batch_size = 32
epochs = 10 
steps_per_epoch = train_imagesize//batch_size

model.fit_generator(
         train_dataset,
         steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
         epochs = epochs,
         validation_data = test_dataset)
```

I get such errors below, which show the error from my `validation_data = test_dataset` line, but I do not really understand the meaning of `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape.

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1932, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5247, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 1)).
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the data, but it seems you have to apply "one-hot-encoding" to your `test_dataset` labels.

Comment: How many classes do you have?

Comment: something is wrong with your data. Please show code

Comment: Yes, updated my full code until the error.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy there shows `Found 327 images belonging to 2 classes.`

Comment: Then you need to adjust the output neurons to 1, sigmoid activation, and then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a binary classification problem, the output layer should have 1 neuron(unit) and a `sigmoid` activation function.
To overcome the error, replace the following line of code:

```
# Output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

with the following code:

```
# Output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```